# getSupportedFlashMode returning 403 error

Tags: camera, sony

This is a question for Sony support, or anyone else who might know.

I'm developing an Android app using the Sony Remote Camera API.  The camera is the Sony RX-10, which isn't on the official list of supported devices but does work with basic functionality (zoom, take photo) and does return a list of supported API calls.  Among the supported API calls are flash mode calls like setFlashMode and getSupportedFlashMode, but when I try calling them they return 403 errors, "Forbidden".  (When I make calls that aren't in the "getAvailableAPIList" list I get error 12, "No Such Method".)  Why are the flash calls returning 403?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is known issue that getAvailableApiList gives protected APIs also. You are able to use only the APIs which are public on supported cameras.

Answer (score 0):

We worked extensively on the RX10 for a photobooth app that we created, and the issue is that the RX10 only works in AUTO mode via the SDK. AUTO mode doesn't support any flash settings other than auto, so it ignores the `get/setFlashMode` commands.

Ultimately we switched to the A6000 which does support other exposure modes that allow the `get/setFlashMode` commands to work correctly.