# Sony Camera Remote API call forbidden?

Tags: api, camera, sony

I have a similar Situation as SkippyFlipjack in his thread:
[getSupportedFlashMode returning 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467747/getsupportedflashmode-returning-403-error/)

It seems that there are a few but not uninteresting API calls which are "protected". They are listed in the getAvailableApiList, but when you use these APIs, you will get error code 403: Forbidden (eg: Camera AS100, API-Call getAvailableCameraFunction)

Is there a way to use the "protected" API calls or are these calls reserved for very special Sony programmer?

And how can I recognize protected API calls? Only with the try-and-error-way?

Other API calls are okay (eg: Camera AS100, Firmware 2.0, API-Calls getAvailableShootMode, setShootMode, actTakePicture, ...).

Greetings from Germany Ralf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to access protected API calls from the Camera Remote SDK.  You can determine which APIs are supported (not protected) from the table "Supported API groups for each compatible cameras" on page 11 of the API reference PDF that comes with the Camera Remote SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and you are right: getAvailableCameraFunction is in camera function which are not supported by the as100 - my fault.

Comment: But the steady mode are in the list on page 12, with no exception. But if I call getAvailableSteadyMode I get error 403: forbidden. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have the latest firmware installed on the camera?

Comment: Yes, I think so: Version 2.0 should be the current Firmware for the AS100, or?

Comment: 2nd fault by myself: I was very sure, that I checked last december the firmaware Version. I thought it was 2.0 but it was 1.0. Now it is 2.0 and everything works as expected. Thanks for your replies.